# After calling python script from Node.js, it does not follow the sequence of execution

Tags: python, node.js

Here is my python code:

```
import smbus
import sys
import time
 x=0
 completeData = "";
 while x<800:
  crgb =  ""+x;
  print crgb
  completeData = completeData + crgb + "@";
  time.sleep(.0001)
  x = x+1
  file = open("sensorData.txt", "w")
  file.write(completeData)
  file.close()
  sys.stdout.flush()
else:
 print "Device not found\n"
```

And this is my Node.js code:

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

PythonShell.run('sensor.py', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('finished');
});
console.log ("Now reading data");
```

:::

```
The output is :
Now reading data
finished
```

My Target is to write the data using python and then read this data using node.js. But the problem is the program first executes the reading function and then writing.

How can I first complete the writing using python then reading using node.js???

Any help will be appreciated !! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Put your read code inside of callback. JavaScript is synchronous and you code is not.

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

PythonShell.run('sensor.py', function (err) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log('finished');
   console.log ("Now read data");
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know this way it works. But I have to read the data outside of  'PythonShell.run (){}' function. Because this is the part of a big project and following calculations are depending on these data. Is there any other way that I can execute the code sequentially outside of the 'PythonShell.run (){}' function.

Comment: You can use nodejs exec or spawn  https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html   ...but they also will be Async...So the best way is to run method for reading after callback is received in others cases i'm not sure that all data will write properly.

Comment: As far as i see you know python...JavaScript similar to that language in case of sync behave, but in JS we have callbacks which means that i don't care what happends next...i just run it and go to next line and callback will handle response. In your case. Data don't be written into file but last console already been processed. That's why you need a callback to handle this kind of operation.Or you can rewrite code from python in NodeJs to write data into file in sync way.

Comment: Try this if you will use node. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_file_data_options_callback .Method fs.appendFileSync(file, data[, options]) . Dont forget try catch.